# Matplotlib.pyplot labels not displaying Hindi text in Labels,

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a function, which looks somewhat like this and it displays a distribution plot which has the y-axis labels in Hindi.

```
def dispersionPlot(text, words):
    tokens = tok.wordtokenize(text)
    print(words)
    x_length = len(tokens)
    y_length = len(words)
    x_list = []
    y_list = []
    for i in range(0 , x_length):
        for j in range(0 , y_length):
            if tokens[i] == words[j]:
                x_list.append(i+1)
                y_list.append(j)
    plt.plot(x_list, y_list, "b|", scalex=.1)
    plt.yticks(list(range(len(words))), words, color="b")
    plt.ylim(-1, len(words))
    plt.xlabel("Lexical Distribution")
    plt.show()
```

Now when I try calling the function with Hindi text. Then I get an output somewhat like this.

```
text = "प्रदूषण आज के समय का सबसे बड़ा अभिशाप है जो हमारे विज्ञानं की देन है। प्रदूषण के बढ़ने से हमारे धरती पे बहुत सी समस्याएं पैदा हो गई जिसे अगर समय रहते न रोक गया तो वो दिन दूर नही जब धीरे-धीरे सब खतम हो जायेगा। प्रदुषण के तत्त्व मनुष्यों द्वारा उत्पन्न किया गया पदार्थ या वेस्ट मटेरियल होता है जो की प्राकृतिक संसाधन जैसे की वायु, जल और भूमि आदि को प्रदूषित करते है| प्रदूषण जहरीली गैस, कीटनाशक, शाकनाशी, कवकनाशी, ध्वनि, कार्बनिक मिश्रण, रेडियोधर्मी पदार्थ हो सकते है। दिन पर दिन वनो की कटाई, कारखानो का प्रदूषित धुआं, वाहनो का धुँआ हमारे पूरे वातावरण को दूषित करता जा रहा है। प्रदूषण कई तरह के होते है परन्तु इनमे से सबसे हानिकारक जल प्रदूषण, वायु प्रदूषण, और ध्वनि प्रदूषण है। नगरो का सारा कूड़ा करकट और मल जल में डाल दिया जाता है जिससे हमारे पीने का पानी अशुद्ध हो गया है और इसके सेवन से हमारे शरीर को अनेक तरह की बीमारियां लग रही है। वायु प्रदूषण हमारे द्वारा उत्पन की गई गसो से पूरी हवा में फ़ैल जाता है और वही दूषित हवा को हम श्वास के साथ अंदर लेते है और कई तरह की बिमारियों का शिकार बन जाते है। ध्वनि प्रदूषण का कारण बढ़ती जनसख्या है जिसके कारण शोरगुल बढ़ता जा रहा है जैसे की वाहनो का शोर, कारखानो में मशीनो का शोर इत्यादि । प्रदूषण पर नियंत्रण पाने के लिए संयुक्त प्रयास की आवश्यकता है जिससे की हम एक स्वस्थ्य और प्रदुषण मुक्त वातावरण पा सके।"
words = ["है", "प्रदूषण"]
dispersionPlot(text, words)
```

[image: Output]

As you can see the Hindi words in y-ticks don't get displayed. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently matplotlib doesn't know how to render the characters. One way to solve this is to tell matplotlib which font to use. For example, say you will use "Nirmala". Put the font file at a proper location and you can code like this:

Note: I'm not sure how your `tok.wordtokenize(text)` works (similar to `nltk`'s `word_tokenize(s)`?). So I changed that line to `tokens = text.split()`. Hope you won't mind.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties

def dispersionPlot(text, words):
    tokens = text.split()
    print(words)
    x_length = len(tokens)
    y_length = len(words)
    x_list = []
    y_list = []
    for i in range(0 , x_length):
        for j in range(0 , y_length):
            if tokens[i] == words[j]:
                x_list.append(i+1)
                y_list.append(j)
    plt.plot(x_list, y_list, "b|", scalex=.1)
    hindi_font = FontProperties(fname = 'Nirmala.ttf')
    plt.yticks(list(range(len(words))), words, color="b", fontproperties=hindi_font)
    plt.ylim(-1, len(words))
    plt.xlabel("Lexical Distribution")
    plt.show()

text = "प्रदूषण आज के समय का सबसे बड़ा अभिशाप है जो हमारे विज्ञानं की देन है। प्रदूषण के बढ़ने से हमारे धरती पे बहुत सी समस्याएं पैदा हो गई जिसे अगर समय रहते न रोक गया तो वो दिन दूर नही जब धीरे-धीरे सब खतम हो जायेगा। प्रदुषण के तत्त्व मनुष्यों द्वारा उत्पन्न किया गया पदार्थ या वेस्ट मटेरियल होता है जो की प्राकृतिक संसाधन जैसे की वायु, जल और भूमि आदि को प्रदूषित करते है| प्रदूषण जहरीली गैस, कीटनाशक, शाकनाशी, कवकनाशी, ध्वनि, कार्बनिक मिश्रण, रेडियोधर्मी पदार्थ हो सकते है। दिन पर दिन वनो की कटाई, कारखानो का प्रदूषित धुआं, वाहनो का धुँआ हमारे पूरे वातावरण को दूषित करता जा रहा है। प्रदूषण कई तरह के होते है परन्तु इनमे से सबसे हानिकारक जल प्रदूषण, वायु प्रदूषण, और ध्वनि प्रदूषण है। नगरो का सारा कूड़ा करकट और मल जल में डाल दिया जाता है जिससे हमारे पीने का पानी अशुद्ध हो गया है और इसके सेवन से हमारे शरीर को अनेक तरह की बीमारियां लग रही है। वायु प्रदूषण हमारे द्वारा उत्पन की गई गसो से पूरी हवा में फ़ैल जाता है और वही दूषित हवा को हम श्वास के साथ अंदर लेते है और कई तरह की बिमारियों का शिकार बन जाते है। ध्वनि प्रदूषण का कारण बढ़ती जनसख्या है जिसके कारण शोरगुल बढ़ता जा रहा है जैसे की वाहनो का शोर, कारखानो में मशीनो का शोर इत्यादि । प्रदूषण पर नियंत्रण पाने के लिए संयुक्त प्रयास की आवश्यकता है जिससे की हम एक स्वस्थ्य और प्रदुषण मुक्त वातावरण पा सके।"
words = ["है", "प्रदूषण"]
dispersionPlot(text, words)
```

[image]

Comment: I am using this function in a package will, relative file address work?

Comment: The [document](https://matplotlib.org/api/font_manager_api.html?highlight=fontproperties#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties) says "Alternatively, a font may be specified using an absolute path to a .ttf file, by using the fname kwarg". I would say give a try.

Comment: This is not rendering text properly. Note how प्रदूषण is rendered in y label